# Что значит удаленная ветка ,но локальная?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-clone, branch

""Удалённые ветки - это "специальные локальные ветки" задача которых указывать на состояние ветки в удаленном репозитории на момент последней синхронизации между локальным и удаленным репозиторием""

Это цитата из курса по GIT. Я не могу ее понять. Почему удаленные ветки это локальные ветки? И где посмотреть как они "указывают на состояние ветки в удаленном репозитории на момент ..."

Comment: "локальная ветка" здесь имеется ввиду что она на вашей локальной машине, в локальной копии репозитория. Тоесть если отключиться от сервера, ветка все равно будет у вас. Она есть и на удаленном сервере, потому и удаленная и локальная одновременно. Понимаю, не так очевидно, но изучать git в качестве первой системы контроля версий не совсем имеет смысл

Comment: Есть локальная ветка на вашей машине, есть внешняя на GitHub-е. Чтобы синхронизировать изменения между ними, необходимо задать соответствие, которое хранится локально на вашей машине. Это и имеется в виду в цитате. `git remote -v` покажет для текущей локальной ветки её fetch (откуда берём внешние изменения) и push (куда добавляем локальные изменения) remotes.

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается я понимал все что написано в цитате , просто сама цитата была слишком запутанно сформулирована